# Refactor packages when moving clases

Tags: intellij-idea

I was wondering if there is a way to move clases form one package to another without refactoring package name.

And if possible, after that, do the refactoring of the whole packages and references of the application, maybe with an inspection or something.

Comment: Does drag and drop on the classes, resulting in the "Move specified classes" Dialog, do what you want?

Comment: Drag and drop does the refactor automatically (it changes tha package name). I want to disable this feature in the movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's a hacky way to move classes around without refactoring.

- Above your source files, find the source root marked in blue. For example if you are using standard maven layout then it will be src/main/java - right click on `java`, select *Mark Directory As* -> *Unmark as source root*
- Notice that your java files are no longer recognized as java source - you can drag and drop your files, and the package name should not be factored.
- Remark your `java` folder as a source root - *Mark Directory As* -> *Source Root*

Hope this helps!